# Vertical alignment of flex item in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've been trying to flex elements to align in center of their respective divs by using all possible variations like

```
align-items:center;
align-self: center;
justify-content: center;
text-align: center;
```

However, I'm unable to get the flex items to center in the flex box. Here is an example of how it looks like: https://jsfiddle.net/skd/xypmLspe/1/

**Flex Group**

```
.flex-group {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 400px;
    background: grey;
    align-items: center;
    align-self: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**Flex items**

```
.flex-group .flex {
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.6s;
    transition: background 0.6s;
}

.flex-group .flex:hover {
    background-color: #34373c;
}
```

In the jssfiddle example shown above, I'm want to align "Blah" and "Another Blah" to the center of the div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `flex: 1` on both inner div's so that each one take half of parents width and then also add `display: flex`, `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center` to center text inside them.

```css
body {margin: 0}

.flex-group {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  background: grey;
}
.flex-group .flex {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: background 0.6s;
}
.flex-group .flex:hover {
  background-color: #34373c;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-group">
  <span class="flex">Blah</span>
  <span class="flex">Another Blah</span>
</div>
```